# CSS: How to make the span not changing in sizes each time it is refreshed for digital clock

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am now making a simple digital clock such as follows:

```js
function displayTime(){
//get current time 
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var hours = currentTime.getHours();
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
 var meridien = "AM";
//added 0 to front of hours, minutes and seconds for asthetic display
if (seconds < 10){
  seconds = "0" + seconds;
}

if (minutes < 10){
  minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

if (hours < 10){
 hours = "0" + hours;
}

// Display AM and PM Logic 
 if (hours > 12){
  meridien = "PM";
 } else {
  meridien = "AM";
 }


var clockDis = document.getElementById("clock");
var meridienDis = document.getElementById("meridiem");
clockDis.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds ;
meridienDis.textContent = meridien;

}
//refresh every seconds
setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
displayTime();
```

```css
span{

 font-size: 100px;
 text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Clock </title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<span id="clock"></span>
<span id="meridiem"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is working fine BUT there is little aesthetic issues happened at areas between seconds and meridiem (AM/PM) part where the merdiem will twitch left and right each time the seconds update itself. How do I make all the span not changing in terms of width so that meridiem will stay at a fixed position each time the seconds refreshed. Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: You could make it so the seconds dots dont turn on and off, but change opacity instead, so they are always there, just not visible. That should keep the spacing intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a monospaced font:

```
font-family: monospace;
```

In a monospaced font, every character has the same width, so replacing one digit with another won't change the width of the text. (The text above is in a monospaced font, for example.)

Comment: Awesome, it solves the problem right away with this line. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
#container span{
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px; //or whatever
}
```

Comment: Interesting solutions but I need to play around the width values which may not be practical if I am keep updating the clocks with functionality in future. But it can solves the problem for now. Thanks @see sharper